# Are these weird functions continuous?

Tags: calculus, functions

I have encountered this question:
The symbol $(x)$ denotes the largest integer less than or equal to $x$. Thus $(2.1) = 2$ and $(-0.9) = (-1) = -1$. At which points are the following functions continuous?

a) $f(x) = (x)$

b) $f(x) = x - (x)$

c) $f(x) = (1/x)$

I am having trouble visualizing these functions. I'd say the first and third one will be not continuous and the second continuous. Could you confirm/deny this and explain why it might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html

Comment: Using plain round parentheses with such a meaning seems to be a sure way to invite confusion. Why not use the standard notation $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: Try graphing those functions

Answer (score 1):

I think none of these three function are continuous function.

For the first and third functions, the reason is simple: $f(x) \in {\mathbb Z}$.

For the second function, it is not continuous at $x \in {\mathbb Z}$.

I attach three pictures for you :-)

The first one is function $f(x) = (x)$
[image]

The second one is function $f(x) = x - (x)$

[image]

The third on is function $f(x) = (1/x)$

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But then how can I specify for which points these functions are continuous? Take function 1 for instance, I can't possibly give every interval ever. Is there some sort of convention for this? Thanks!

Comment: For functions 1 and 2, they are continuous on $[k, k+1)$ ($k \in {\mathbb Z}$). For function 3, it is continuous on $(-\infty, -1]$ and $(-1/k, -1/(k+1)]$ ($k \in {\mathbb Z}_+$) for $x < 0$; $(1/(k+1), 1/ k]$ ($k \in {\mathbb Z}_+$) and $(1, \infty)$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: For more general functions, the continuity should be judged by its definition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function for an example.

Comment: Note that the continuity can be defined on more general topological space rather than ${\mathbb R}$, where the definition plays a pivotal role since the graphs ususally cannot be embedded into ${\mathbb R}^3$.